# TChart: Error reading TLineSeries.CustomVertAxis: Argument out of range

Tags: delphi, teechart

I am trying to load in a TChart. I can successfully load a chart and all its data as long as I save the chart with no custom axis. If I change the axis before saving the chart, when I load it back I get the following error message:

"Error Reading TLineSeries.CustomVertAxis: Argument out of range."

If I take a look at the .tee file that is saved when I use custom axis, this is what I'm seeing:

```
object TLineSeries
Title = 'A'
VertAxis = aCustomVertAxis
Brush.BackColor = clDefault
Pointer.InflateMargins = True
Pointer.Style = psRectangle
XValues.DateTime = True
XValues.Name = 'X'
XValues.Order = loAscending
YValues.Name = 'Y'
YValues.Order = loNone
CustomVertAxis = -1
Data = {...
```

Like I said, if I load a chart with no custom axis it works just fine. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Want to ask again: Do you really need to save a load whole component?

Comment: I got around this by setting the custom axis from each series to nil before saving. And yes, the application I am using this for is to bring up all the data collected and be able to review it in the chart. Therefore I need all series and their respective data to be saved and loaded.